# Receiving `net::ERR_ABORTED ` only for included .js files

Tags: node.js, express

I used the [express generator linked here](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html) to build a scaffold.

The 2nd thing I did was put two different 2ndary js files into place `/public/js/useeasel.js` and `/public/js/libs/createjs.min.js`

The 3rd thing I did was change the views to call those files like so

layout.hbs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{{title}}</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
        <script src='/js/lib/createjs.min.js'></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        {{{body}}}
    </body>
</html>
```

index.hbs

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<p>Welcome to {{title}}</p>

<div onload="init();">
    <canvas id="cid" width=2000 height=3000></canvas>
</div>
<script src="/js/useeasel.js"></script>
```

End result:

```
localhost/:6 GET http://localhost:3000/js/lib/createjs.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED
localhost/:16 GET http://localhost:3000/js/useeasel.js net::ERR_ABORTED
```

Bottom line is I did 3 things, edited ***nothing else***, and received these error messages.

I tried jackin with app.js `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));` but ultimately wound up just putting it back as nothing helped.

A weird thing tho. . . occasionally I'll get:

```
 localhost/:16 GET http://localhost:3000/js/useeasel.js 404 (Not Found)
```

ONLY for that file. And sometimes, even, there's 2 entries for that file, one of each of the above errors.

The `/stylesheets/style.css` file works, and when I moved those 2 files to the `/stylesheets/` dir (and changed the script call) they still didn't work, so I guess something is puking on .js files, but since I'm just running the express tutorials I've not the slightest.

What do I need to change here to make the js files work and the error messages go away?